# AndEngine Vector2 operations change my variable

Tags: java, android, andengine

I don't know why but this part of my code is changing my variable: toMovePosition

```
bodyNpc.setLinearVelocity(toMovePosition.sub(bodyNpc.getPosition()).nor());
```

Code:

```
private void createPhysics(final Camera camera, PhysicsWorld physicsWorld) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        bodyNpc = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(physicsWorld, this, BodyType.KinematicBody, PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0, 0));

        bodyNpc.setUserData("N" + ArrayPosition);

        physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(this, bodyNpc, true, false)
        {
            @Override
            public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed)
            {
                super.onUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);

                if(toMovePosition != null){ //Si te on anar
                    bodyNpc.setLinearVelocity(toMovePosition.sub(bodyNpc.getPosition()).nor());
                    Log.w("Npc", ""+toMovePosition);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Variables:

```
public Body bodyNpc;
private Vector2 toMovePosition;
```

Getters and setters:

```
public void setToMovePosition(float px, float py){
    this.toMovePosition = new Vector2(px, py);
}

public Vector2 getToMovePosition(){
    return this.toMovePosition; 
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the methods `sub(Vector2)` and `nor()` change the values of `toMovePosition` object as you can see in [source](https://code.google.com/p/andenginephysicsbox2dextension/source/browse/src/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.java?r=9941687b322c1cbb5cbc2fabb49620c34b94890e).

`Vector2` class have a copy constructor defined so you could just wrap `toMovePosition` like this - `bodyNpc.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(toMovePosition).sub(bodyNpc.getPosition()).nor());` 
 
This should result in unmodified `toMovePosition` object.